# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 23, Size: 23

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to display the total number of links and link names, I had my code but its have IndexOutOfBoundsException error

```
    String BaseURL = "http://istp.in/changathionlinebeta/index.php";
    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
    wd.get(BaseURL);

    // get size
    java.util.List<WebElement> links = wd.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println("Total Number Of Links: " + links.size());

    // display links
    for (int i = 0; i <= links.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
        links.get(i).click();
        wd.navigate().back();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
i < links.size()
```

instead of

```
i <= links.size() because size return 23 but index start from 0 that means the last(23rd) element index is 22
```

one important thing, after

```
wd.navigate().back();
```

ur code will show u an error. so try the below;

```
  String BaseURL = "http://istp.in/changathionlinebeta/index.php";
WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
wd.get(BaseURL);

// get size
java.util.List<WebElement> links = wd.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println("Total Number Of Links: " + links.size());


int size = links.size();
// display links
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    java.util.List<WebElement> linksloop = wd.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println(linksloop.get(i).getText());
    linksloop.get(i).click();
    wd.navigate().back();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it wrong to create `linksLoop` every time the for-loop runs. It should be defined outside the loop.

Comment: @ rupinderjeet47  no ... as he navigate back, driver will not find the previous dom element and will show a error.... thats why i suggest him every time to created linksloop

Comment: `java.util.List<WebElement> linksloop;` and then `for-loop` and then the initialization of `linksLoop` in `for-loop` as `linksloop = wd.findElements(By.tagName("a"));`  Is separating declaration and initialization wrong in this code?

Comment: @ rupinderjeet47 first run acmsadik code in ur machine and than see what happens and than give a suggestion how u will fix that error ...... i think u are not familiar with that error

Comment: yes its works noor the IndexOutOfBoundsException error is removed but there is another problem ::Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds

Comment: yes .... thats why i suggest u to use my code.... i hope my code will work fine and will not show any error ...... thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
    ...
}
```

replaced `<=` with `<`

scroll to `size` method at [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).
It returns total number of elements, for example 23. But, you were checking from `i=0` to `i<=23` which is actually 24 elements.

Iterating from `i=0` to `i<links.size()` makes it check for 23 elements.